# Is Rogue Group/Rogue Squadron named after Rogue One (in-universe)?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, the-empire-strikes-back

In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Luke Skywalker leads "Rogue Group" at the Battle of Hoth:

> Rogue Group, use your harpoons and tow cables. Go for the legs. It might be our only chance of stopping them.

In other media, this organization is referred to as "Rogue Squadron".

While this movie came out over 35 years before *Rogue One*, it chronologically takes place after it. In current canon, was "Rogue Group"/"Rogue Squadron" named after the titular "Rogue One" group?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Marvel's new Star Wars comics #52, Luke names their new squadron, and references Jyn Erso while naming it.

[image: Luke stating where the name comes from]

[image: Chronologically first reference to Rogue Squadron in Canon]

Comment: In universe, I can't argue - IRL however obviously Rogue One was not on the radar when ESB was written, and as rebels, the rogue could have come from any number of origins.

Comment: Right, and if we're basing if off of old, pre-Disney canon, then we'd have to look at EU Novels or Comics to answer the question, but the original question asked about current canon, so thanks to the magic of retcon, they can interconnect any Star Wars property to any other as they see fit. :P